# Best way to pull non-optional values from optional containers

Tags: swift

This is a best practices question, and I have a feeling I'm missing an obvious solution...

I was stumped why this bit of code made it past the if when `wantsGroundAlways` was false and `I1` was undefined:

```
let i = c.data["I1"]?.integerValue
if !wantsGroundAlways && i == 0 { return }
```

The problem was that `data["I1"]` is, by definition, optional, so Swift inferred `i` as `int?`, and nil != 0. Subtle, but obvious in retrospect.

But what *is* the best way to deal with this common case? One solution is:

```
let i = (c.data["I1"] ?? 0).integerValue
```

But personally I think that looks terrible and hides the intent. Something along the lines of:

```
guard let i = c.data["I1"]?.integerValue else { i = 0 }
```

would make it obvious what you're trying to do, but it doesn't work because the i cannot be accessed in the else clause and `{ let i = 0 }` is not the same `i` (try it, you'll see what I mean).

Now there is this:

```
guard let arcradius = c.data["F1"]?.doubleValue else { return }
```

which seems *really* close to what I want to do, but I'm not sure this is really what I think it means - will the return really fire if F1 is not in the dict? And what is the difference between that version and this:

```
guard case let arcradius = c.data["F1"]?.doubleValue else { return }
```

Which tells me it's always true?

I think I am missing something key here... so what do you all do in these situations?

Comment: Why don't just check if `i == nil`?

Comment: @Code: It's amazing how often we forget that we can still do simple, "old-school"-style `nil` checks.

Comment: @NRitH They're generally discouraged in Swift. There's almost always a better way.

Comment: @AlexanderMomchliov, what's the better way here?

Comment: @NRitH See my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think this is the most straightforward and expressive way of solving your first question:

```
let i = c.data["I1"]?.integerValue ?? 0
```

It doesn't require brackets, and shows intent.

`??` is the *nil coalescence operator*. It's a binary operator. If the left operand is not `nil`, it's returned, otherwise the right operand is returned.

`c.data["I1"]` can be `nil` (because there might be no value for the `"I1"` key). In such a case, `c.data["I1"]?.integerValue` will be `nil`. The `??` will then return the `0`. If all goes well, and the left side isn't `nil`, it'll be returned, ignoring the `0`.

Comment: So does this basically fail over to the ?? when the ? tests? If so, yes, that is precisely what I want, and it was obvious, and I do feel silly.

Comment: I'll break it down in my answer

Answer (score 1):

If you want only to check if a key exist or not then a "type cast" to `Int` or `Double` is irrelevant.

Why not simply

```
guard c.data["I1"] == nil && !wantsGroundAlways else { return }
```

It passes the test if `I1` is not in the dictionary and `wantsGroundAlways` is `false`.

`if let` or `guard let` is not needed either because according the condition the value for key is never used.